# Добавить к коду функцию setTimeout

Tags: javascript, setinterval, settimeout

```
document.getElementById("visually").onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById("die").classList.add("block__active");
  document.getElementById("die").classList.remove("block__hidden");
};
```

Есть часть кода.
Нужно, что б после клика, она срабатывала через 2 секунды.

Попробовал таким макаром, но видимо, что-то упустил:

```
function f() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById("visually").onclick = function () {
      document.getElementById("die").classList.add("block__active");
      document.getElementById("die").classList.remove("block__hidden");
    };
  }, 2000);
}
```

Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного не так.

Вы определили функцию, но не вызвали её:

```
  const someMethod = function () {
    document.getElementById("die").classList.add("block__active");
    document.getElementById("die").classList.remove("block__hidden");
  }

  const f = function () {
      setTimeout( someMethod, 2000);
  }

  document.getElementById("visually").onclick = f;
```

Думаю, как-то так применительно к вашему коду.